# Is it possible to alias or subclass the Annotated type in Python and pass mypy validation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, python-typing

These are my attempts so far, using Python 3.10:

```py
from typing import Annotated, NewType, TypeAlias

AsTypeAlias: TypeAlias = Annotated
# Annotated[...] must have exactly one type argument and at least one annotation   

AsNewType = NewType('AsNewType', Annotated)  
# Argument 2 to NewType(...) must be a valid type; Annotated[...] must have exactly one type argument and at least one annotation

AsVariableAssignment = Annotated
# no error 
Test: AsVariableAssignment[str, 'annotation']  
# Variable "annotation_test.AsVariableAssignment" is not valid as a type;  Name "annotation" is not defined

class AsSubClass(Annotated):  
    pass
#  INTERNAL ERROR - mypy crashes
```

Am I trying to do something that I shouldn't be doing?

Answer (score 1):

Just like some other types in the module `typing`, `Annotate` is not a regular type, but rather a [special form](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#special-forms) that can be used ***as a type in annotations with `[]`***. Without `[]`, `Annotation` is not a valid type. You cannot alias it, and you should not subclass it.

## TypeAlias

`TypeAlias` allows you explicitly alias *a type*, while `Annotated` is not.

```
AsTypeAlias: TypeAlias = Annotated
# Annotated[...] must have exactly one type argument and at least one annotation
```

## NewType

This is invalid for the same reason. `Annotated` is not a valid type without `[]`.

```
AsNewType = NewType('AsNewType', Annotated)  
# Argument 2 to NewType(...) must be a valid type; Annotated[...] must have exactly one type argument and at least one annotation
```

## Implicit Definition of a Type Alias

In Python, you can either explicitly create a type alias (with `TypeAlias` in [PEP 613](https://peps.python.org/pep-0613/)) or implicitly via `Alias = SomeType`.

One crucial task for the type checker for the latter case is figuring out the semantic `=`. Is it a regular variable assignment or an implicit type alias definition?

Consider the different between

```
MyInt = int

# No error
def foo(a: MyInt): ...
```

and

```
MyInt = 5

# Variable "alt.MyInt" is not valid as a type
def foo(a: MyInt): ...
```

The first example implicitly create a type alias, while the second one creates a variable. This seems trivial, but it in fact reflects that the type checker decides whether `MyInt` should be a type alias or not by checking the type of the expression on the right hand side of the assignment. This is also the case when we are trying to do

```
AsVariableAssignment = Annotated
```

mypy needs to know if the RHS [is a valid type or not](https://github.com/python/mypy/blob/f9dadb13daca61bdf7972c95c36071956e7d3b43/mypy/semanal.py#L2194-L2211). It handles special forms like `Annotated` as a special case.

Only `Tuple`, `Callable`, `Any` are special forms that are valid types without `[]`, and `Annotated` is not one of them. Therefore, mypy infers that `AsVariableAssignment = Annotated` is a variable assignment as `Annotated` is not a valid type, leading to the error `Variable "annotation_test.AsVariableAssignment" is not valid as a type` since it considers `AsVariableAssignment` as a variable.

## `'annotation'` Is Not `Literal['annotation]`

Mypy thinks `'annotation'` is a string type, so it looks for the definition of a type that is named `annotation`, in this case, you should use `Literal['annotation']` instead. This error has nothing to do with `Annotated`.

```
AsVariableAssignment = Annotated
# no error 
Test: AsVariableAssignment[str, 'annotation']  
# Variable "annotation_test.AsVariableAssignment" is not valid as a type;  Name "annotation" is not defined
```

## Subclassing

Many special forms cannot be subclassed, and mypy should normally give an error like this:

```
# error: Invalid base class "Union"
class AsSubClass(Union):
    pass
```

While the following crashes mypy. This is likely a bug that should be reported.

```
class AsSubClass(Annotated):  
    pass
```

Here is the traceback.

```
error: INTERNAL ERROR -- Please try using mypy master on Github:
https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#using-a-development-mypy-build
Please report a bug at https://github.com/python/mypy/issues
version: 0.930
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mypy/semanal.py", line 5132, in accept
  File "mypy/nodes.py", line 1005, in accept
  File "mypy/semanal.py", line 1105, in visit_class_def
  File "mypy/semanal.py", line 1127, in analyze_class
  File "mypy/semanal.py", line 1337, in clean_up_bases_and_infer_type_variables
  File "mypy/semanal.py", line 1428, in get_all_bases_tvars
  File "mypy/types.py", line 615, in accept
  File "mypy/typeanal.py", line 1296, in visit_unbound_type
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```